# Limit max day of Data for all months

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

I need to calculate, over months, the value of Sales in every month limiting the max day of my data = my Day(DateTimeNow()) - 1.

Examples:
Today is 25 of march, i wanna see in my bar chart the total of Sales until day 24 for january, february and march.

Today is 02 of april, my bar chart will show the sales of day 1 for january, february, march and april.

I've tried using limit data in my graph like so I set the max day of my Date to be the `Day(DateTimeNow()) - 1`

`Max(Day([DATE])) = Day(DateTimeNow()) - 1`

That way I set the max Day for my date to be equal my Day - 1

I've tried using ParallelPeriod too.

I expect that using:
  `Max(Day([DATE])) = Day(DateTimeNow()) - 1`

I've got like: 
   `Max(Day([DATE])) = 31`

`Day(DateTimeNow()) - 1 = 02`

`( Max(Day([DATE])) = Day(DateTimeNow()) - 1 )`

I know that this results in a boolean expression, so:
    31 = 02  -> False

But i just want to set the Max Day to be 02.

Answer (score 1):

This expression below should fit your needs. Put this expression in the `Limit data using expression` of the `visualization options`.

```
Day([DATE])<Day(DateTimeNow())-1
```

It takes, for each months, the days before `current day - 1`. If we are on the first of the month, then no data will be available.